# "Project Key is not associated with current project" trying to set up Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to publish a Google Docs addon, visible only to my Google Apps domain, and then automatically install it for everyone in the domain

I have:

1. made a script in Google Drive, shared it with everyone on the domain
2. deployed it to the Developer Dashboard using `Publish -> Deploy as Addon`, with `Publish in Google Apps Marketplace` turned OFF
3. pushed it from the Developer Dashboard, making it visible just to users of my domain, giving it all the necessary fields and images
4. verified that others from the domain can install the addon by going to `Addons -> Get addons` in a Google Doc, toggling the filter to `For mydomain.com`. Also verified that it works when installed that way.
5. created a new project in `Google Developers Console`, added Google Marketplace SDK and created an OAuth2 client id

I'm stuck on the step of "configure Marketplace SDK", specifically the project key for the `Docs add-on extension` option in it, where I'm consistently getting a `Project Key is not associated with current project.` error.

I believe I need to finish this step, so that I could then re-do step 2 with `Publish in Google Apps Marketplace` turned ON, and then finally enable it for everyone.

Steps that shouldn't affect things, but might be worth noting:

- I am not the owner/admin of the domain, but the admin is assisting in steps where I get stuck. (like creating the OAuth2 client id)
- I have transferred ownership of the Developer Dashboard entry to a group that I'm owner of (on the desired domain)
- I have transferred ownership of the Developer Console project to that same group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was I manually created a project in `Google Developers Console`

instead, I should've used the `Resources -> Advanced Google Services -> Google Developers Console` link to access a HIDDEN PROJECT (?!) and enable Marketplace SDK there.

sigh.

Comment: Looks like for [viewing purposes](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4847#c5), projects created within .gs can't be accessed at console.developers.google.com. First creating a project at console.developers.google.com and then finding out you can't use it within .gs is confusing.

Comment: @BryanP: thanks for that link, that is *exactly* the issue I had, only the symptoms I was having weren't leading me to Google in that direction... I was trying to bridge it from the other side and all I could see was an error that made no sense.

Comment: This led us to a solution. We had a script project I created and was trying to transfer ownership to the client. I had to go to `Resources -> Cloud platform project...` and manually transfer the project associated to the project id the client had manually configured on GCP.