# Unable to publish Google Docs add-on after review and updating

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

After reviewing the feedback I received after trying to publish my add-on and correcting all deficiencies, I am not ready to re-publish my work. When I attempt to do so, I receive the following error:

[image]

So, after reading a bit, I managed to get to the Google Developer's Console and enable Google Apps Marketplace SDK. Republishing after enabling this library didn't seem to fix the above message, so I tried filling out the configuration as well. I get the following error when doing so:

[image]

This doesn't make any sense because I copied the Project Key direction from the Project properties dialog:

[image]

I didn't have this issue at all when I published originally so I don't have any idea what changed. I also cannot find any useful documentation to overcome this issue. At this point I am unable to republish my updated project. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You may want to check [Publishing Add-ons for Domain-Wide Installation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide) and see what else you missed. It was noted that there is sometimes a delay when publishing or republishing an add-on, but usually less than an hour which could have happened in this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028456/publishing-a-google-docs-add-on-project-key-is-not-associated-with-the-current).

Comment: In addition to that, if you're trying to [bundle an add-on with an Marketplace app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide#bundling_with_an_existing_google_apps_marketplace_app), you must [associate the add-on with the Marketplace app's Developers Console project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#using_a_different_google_developers_console_project).

Comment: This isn't a timing problem, it's been months. Also, I just want to publish the add-on. I simply try to publish from the "Publish" menu in my project and get the errors I describe. I'm not sure how I could have made a mistake when all I do is enter information and click a button.