# What does "Sheets Add-on Script version" refer to in Google Workspace Marketplace SDK configuration?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I am filling out the configuration screen for the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK, that I just enabled in my GCP project. It is for a Google Sheets add-on. I checked the box "Sheets Add-on" and I am now prompted for:

- Sheets Add-on Project Script ID - This I have from the Apps Script Project setting, a 57 character alphanumeric string (if I counted right).
- Sheets Add-on  script version - What do I enter here?

There used to be version numbers for the script code in the classic Apps Scripts IDE, but not in the new IDE. And anyway, it seems unlikely that this is what the GWM SDK is asking for.

I tried just entering "1.0" and got this error:

> Project Key is not associated with the current project or the script version doesn't exist.

What are they looking for and where do I find this?

Comment: The vague "version number" requirement has [confused many developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028456/publishing-a-google-docs-add-on-project-key-is-not-associated-with-the-current/73917597#73917597). Please vote for the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296561635) to have that clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a new version on the new IDE, first create a new deployment.

Then, on the GWM SDK, write the version as `1` (or the corresponding version number), not `1.0`.

Resource

- [Versions - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions)

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Thanks also for the link to the Learn Apps Script guide. I totally missed that one.