# Publishing Google Script Addon to G Suite Marketplace SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I've got some Google Sheet script code that I'd like to extract into Google Sheet Addon to be published for just of our domain (not public web).  Individuals on my team have been able to do this successfully in the past but after [1/25/2019 when Google removed Add-Ons from Google Chrome Store](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration) we've been having difficulties.

I am trying to follow:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons#publishing_instructions

But get the following error when trying to configure the G Suite Marketplace API:

```
Project Key is not associated with current project or the script version doesn't exist.
```

[image: error]

I am pulling the project Key from File --> Project Properties:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong or know of good tutorial of how to publish a private Google Sheet Add-on?

Comment: There is another post with the title of your error.  [Project Key is not associated with current project or the script version doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488959/project-key-is-not-associated-with-current-project-trying-to-set-up-marketplac?rq=1)  Have you seen that answer?

Comment: I think that might be out-of-date - I don't see "Google Developers Console" under the Advance Google Services popup window.  I think they have a dedicated menu: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#accessing_an_apps_script_cloud_platform_project  

I do see that I have "Cloud Platform project" associated with the script which I am trying to configure G Suite Marketplace

Comment: You could make a copy of the project, and publish the copy as an add-on.

Comment: I get the same error with the copy project.

Comment: I just published a stand alone Apps Script file to the G Suite Marketplace as unlisted, and it worked.  So, it doesn't have anything to do with the Project Key. Have you checked the current version of the project from the code editor?  *File -> Manage versions*  Do you have a draft version saved in the Chrome Web Store?

Comment: That's the part I am confused about - Is publishing in the Chrome Web Store is still required?  I thought everything is being transitioned over to G Suite Market?

Comment: The publishing process still takes you to the Chrome Web Store developer dashboard when publishing an add-on.  The Chrome Web Store URL begins with "https://chrome.google.com/webstore" but the G Suite Marketplace URL begins with "https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace"  I can find a link for the unlisted add-on in the marketplace.  If you click the "Preview Changes" button at the bottom of the Developer dashboard, it will open up the listing in the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was still necessary (though maybe Google hasn't updated their publishing wizards)... when I try deploying to Chrome store I get a different error which I've open this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814700/publishing-goggle-sheet-addon-api-console-project-id-error

Comment: In the Chrome Web Store I see the following notification:

"We are phasing out publication of G Suite add-ons and Drive apps to the Chrome Web Store.
Once this process is completed, the G Suite Marketplace will be the only add-on/Drive app store. To avoid losing your listing, you need to also publish it to G Suite Marketplace following the instructions here."

Doesn't this imply that I should not try publishing Add-ons to Chrome Web Store?

Comment: This might be a simple & silly thing but do you use multiple Google Accounts? If so make sure you are signed into the correct one when going into the Marketplace SDK.

Comment: Yep, I have - a good suggestion; I created a separate Chrome session that the only login into my domain account to avoid having switch account from my Gmail account.

Comment: Another simple thing just to check, was is deployed as a Sheets add-on (Menu 'Publish' > 'Deploy as sheets addon') or something else? And just to help clarify, my published Sheets add-on uses the new Script ID, not the depreciated Project Key.

Comment: Yep, I've tried that but get a separate different error message (see comment #8)... in that SO they tell me first fix this problem before deploying as Sheet Addon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem but identified a solution as follows. 
In the Google Apps Script Editor, under Resources -> Cloud Platform Project, click the ProjectName - project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx link. Then when it opens your Cloud Platform Project, in the upper left corner, your project name will be listed with a dropdown. Click the dropdown and verify that this project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx matches the link you clicked. The two numbers did not in my case and I had to refresh my screen for the correct project-id to show up in the Cloud Platform Project screen.

Comment: Make sure you are not logged in with multiple accounts, this can confuse the system as well (no access to project, for instance)

Comment: Yep - verify the project ID in Google Script editor matches the Google Cloud platform

Comment: Yes I have a seperater Chrome session were I am only signed in under the account I am trying publish under

Comment: I started over with a clean project and when I ran into this error again changing the project ID solve the issue.  I've created these instructions from my weeks of trial and error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gG0_EClZC4ztKHDT2yn8v9NmUh_-sqYFe9vGg6Snxgg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help, but I was having the same error message and I just got it to work. I put in the value from  File --> Project Properties: ->Project key (Deprecated) and still got the error. Then I changed the version to the number of my latest version and it worked.

Comment: I only have one version ( '1' ) in Google Script saved... and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Double check your version number - while in the script editor, click on 'File' and 'Project Properties'. I had the same problem. It turns out my error was entering the version name I had given my current version of the script (3.0), instead of the number Google had assigned to the current version of my script (3).

Once I entered '3' as the version number, I no longer got the error message "Project Key is not associated with current project or the script version doesn't exist ", and I was able to save.

I used the 'Project key (Deprecated)'.

Answer (score -1):

The `Project key` has been deprecated. Try using the `Script Id` instead.

Comment: Yep I've tried "Script ID" and the "SDC key" as well; I still get the same error message

Comment: Project key is the correct field to use.  I agree its very confusing that Google says its "deprecated" when its still being activity used.

Comment: The Project key didn't work for me; only the Script ID worked.