# Publishing Google Sheet Addon- api_console_project_id error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, chrome-web-store

I am trying to publish Google Sheet Addon just of users of my domain to install manually (not auto install for all users)

I've extracted my code from Google Sheets into a stand-alone script and try to deploy:

[image]

Which pops up a Chrome Store Listing draft; which I fill out:

[image]

I fill out the long Chrome Store Listing form but when I publish I get:

[image]

> "There is no API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's api_console_project_id field."

My understanding is if you write your code in Google Script editor (https://script.google.com) that you should not and can not modify the project's manifest file so not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This should disappear once you have given your addon access to the Marketplace SDK. ie. Once you've solved [your other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523275/publishing-google-script-addon-to-g-suite-marketplace-sdk).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-cws  "Note: If your app is a Docs, Sheets, Forms, or Slides add-on, Apps Script builds the manifest file for you. You should never need to build or edit this manifest yourself."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chris was right - you have to configure the G-Suite Marketplace first; I've created instructions based on weeks of trial and error:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gG0_EClZC4ztKHDT2yn8v9NmUh_-sqYFe9vGg6Snxgg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a saviour!